# Can I travel with a BRP on a maiden name?

Tags: united-kingdom, names

Good evening!

Perhaps, you could advise on my question. I recently changed my surname to my husband's. My bio metric residence permit was obtained after we already got married. I have applied for the change of bio metric residence permit, but the earliest available appointment is on March 30. The question is can I go abroad and enter the UK back with my old bio metric residence permit before 30 March. I have booked a holiday and bought ticket long time ago. Many thanks for your reply.

PS I am not a European Union citizen

Comment: What name is in your passport?  Wouldn't you have the same problem there?  Regardless, if you bring the legal documents for the name change, that ought to convince the UK border officials.  Whether it would work at your holiday destination probably depends on the destination.

Answer (score 1):

Your old Biometric permit is still valid. Applying for a new one does invalidate the old one. Also, there is nothing that I can find in the immigration rules that states that the name in your passport must absolutely match the name in you BRP, a point that wouldn't apply to you anyway. You may face some issues later when/if you ever decide to get another passport, especially a UK one.